# Did WPF announce a date or a version which will allow UI background thread?

Tags: .net, wpf

Did WPF announce a date or a version which will allow UI background thread?

Comment: Why does it freak you out? Actually, what are you talking about?

Comment: Because Winforms let you do this, right?  And COM wasn't ever thread-centric, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a simple value used in data binding from a background thread, right now.  There have been hints (see [Rob Relyea's PDC talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/PDC/PDC10/CD60)) that some future version of WPF will allow bound collections to be modified from background threads, as well.  This would, I'm sure, not happen until at least the next major release of WPF, as it wasn't included in .NET 4.0.

That being said, there have been no discussions about allowing direct access to UI elements from background threads.